# Project version in tarball downloaded from github master?

Tags: github

I know it is possible to download a tarball with the source code from the `https://github.com/user/repo/archive/master.tar.gz`.

What is the best way to determine the version from that tarball (or possibly through some API)?

Ideally, I want to get the output of `git describe`. Since I don't have the whole repo, I can't run it myself.